# trouble debugging a .bash file that separates and echoes either student or student score

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

Like the title implies, I'm currently having trouble debugging a .bash file. As you can tell, I'm still very new to bash and unix in general. Inside The inputfile that hw3.bash executes on contains the following strings in two columns:

jack 80
mary 95
michael 60
jeffrey 90

The file will print out the names only, then scores only, then highest score, then lowest,  then rank, etc.

Both lines 72 and 150 are the hiccups in the program that i cannot seem to debug. Is this a indentation issue or simply a grammatical issue.

line 72: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 150: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
#1.The first positional argument ($1) provides the file name. Assign it to a
# variable named inputfile.
inputfile=$1

#2.Test if the variable inputfile refers to a file. If not, print out a proper
# message and exit with an exit code of 1.
if [[ -e inputfile ]]; then
   echo "inputfile is not a file'
   exit 1
fi

#3.Suppose each line of the input file is made up of the first name of a 
#student followed by a score (the first name and score are separate by a
# space). Put the first names in the input file into an array called names.
record=( $(cat $inputfile | awk 'END{print NR}' ))
names=( $(cat $inputfile | awk'{print $1}'))
  echo ${names[*]}


#4.Using a similar approach, put the corresponding scores into an
# array called scores.
scores=( $(cat $inputfile | awk'{print $2}'))
  echo ${scores[*]}

#5.Print names and corresponding scores (i.e. output should look the same as
# the input file). You must use a loop to do this.
names=( $(cat $inputfile |  awk'{print $1}'))
  echo${names[*]}
scores=( $(cat $inputfile | awk'{print $2}'))
echo${names[*]}
for((i=0;i<${names[*] && $i<scores[*];i++))
  do 
   echo{$names[i]} {$scores[*]}
  done

#6.Find the highest scorer, and print the name and the score. You may assume
#that there is only one highest score.
maxVal=1
maxIndex=1
for(( i=0; i<$#names[*]} && i<${#scores[*]}; i++ ))
do
    if [[ (-n ${scores[$i]}) ]]
    then 

       if(( ${scores[$i]} > $maxValue ))
       then 
       maxVal=${scores[$i]}
       maxIndex=$i
 fi
    fi
done
echo "Highest Scorer:" ${names[$maxIndex]} " " $maxVal


#7.Find the lowest scorer, and print the name and the score. You may assume
#that there is only one lowest score.
minVal=10000
maxIndex=1
for(( i=0; i<${#names[*]} && i<${#scores[*]}; i++ ))
do
    if [[ (-n ${scores[$i]}) ]]
    then 
        if(( $minVal > ${scores[i]} ))
        then
           minVal=${scores[$i]}
           minIndex=$i;
        fi
done
echo "Lower Scorer:' ${names[$minIndex]} " " $minVal

#8.Calculate the average of all scores, and print it.
avg=0
total=0;

for(( i=0;i<${#names[*]} && i<${$#scores[*]};i++ ))
do
 if [[ (-n ${scores[$i]} ]]
    then 
        total=$(( $total + ${scores[$i]} ))
    fi



#9.Sort the arrays in terms of scores (in descending order). The final
#position of each name in the array names must match with the position of the
# corresponding score in the array scores.

m=${names[*]}
n=${scores[*]}
for(( i=0; i<$n && i<$m; i++ ))
do
  maxValue=1
  maxIndex=0
  for(( i=0; j<$n && j<$m; j++)) 
  do
     if [[ !(-z ${scores[$j]} ) ]]
then
       if (( $maxVal < ${scores[$j]} ))
       then  
          maxVal=${scores[$j]}
          maxIndex=$j

       fi 
     fi
     done
     a1[${#a1[*]}]=$maxVal
a2[${#a2[*]}]=${names[$maxIndex]}
     unset scores[$maxIndex]
  done

 for(( i=0; j<${#a2[*]} && i < ${#a1[*]; i++ ))
do
 echo ${a2[i]} ${a1[i]}
done

#10.Print sorted names and scores. Put the rank of each student before the
m=${#names[*]}
n=${#scores[*]}
for (( i=0; i<$n && i<$m; i++ ))
do 
maxVal=1
maxIndex=0
for (( j=0: j<$n && j<$m; j++ ))
do
  if [[ !_-z ${scores[$j]}) ]]
  then 
    if (( $maxVal < ${scores[$j]}
    maxIndex=$j
    fi 
  fi
  done
a1[${#a1[*]}]=$maxVal
a2[${#a2[*]}=${names[$maxIndex]}
unset scores[$maxIndex]
done
k=1 
while [[ $k -lt ${#a2[*]} ]]
do
  for(( i=0;i < ${#a2[*]} && i < ${#a1[*]};i++ ))
  do

    echo "Ranking" $k "is:" ${a2[i]}
    k=$(($k+1))
  done
done
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting is a clue: you have a string with opening *double* quote and closing *single* quote on line 8.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net would have pointed this out, please always use it. Also, while trying to reduce to a [mcve], you probably would have bumped into the problem; currently, it's not very "minimal".

Answer (score 1):

Like you can see in your line, just before the **then** one, you mixed single and double quotes:

```
echo "inputfile is not a file'
```

Just replace the final simple quote, by a double one.